# use https only for login page not the whole website

Tags: php, https, login-page

i want to open login page of my website with `https` only,not the comeplete website. after login authenication ( successful), website whoud again run on `http`.

currently  my main login page is `test_index.php` where i included `test_header.php`

my basic code on `test_header.php` is

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443) {
   header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
   header("Location: https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   exit();
}
```

but this make complete website in `https`
 i also read [here](http://www.vbulletin.com/forum/showthread.php/230420-https-for-login-only) that it can be possible via `.htaccess`, so i remove above code snippet from `test_header.php` and add the following lines in `.htaccess` file and

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  # 301 redirect to domain to 'www.'
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^testweb.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.testweb.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch test_index.php>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</FilesMatch>
```

*Note: testweb.com is just an imaginary name, not actual website*

but still complete website run on https, please tell me where i m doing mistake??

## Edit

@webbiedave please check my **updated Code** , is that right way??

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/test_index.php') { // only check https on login
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') {
        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
        header("Location: https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        exit();
    } else {
        die("Sorry,Your website is not secure");        
    }
} elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') {
        // header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
        header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        exit();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Going from https to http after login is VERY, VERY insecure.

Comment: @Ginamin but many websites, even `facebook` too do so..i have seen

Comment: @diEcho Many websites also use very bad markup.

Comment: @gnur i m recommending only popular websites like `facebook`, `twitter` etc...

Comment: Yes, Facebook do it and this is the result: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firesheep

Comment: @diEcho Yes Facebook does it, but that doesn't make it correct. You can hit up a search in here and find many reasons why it is insecure. Also, how many times have you seen a facebook update 'I've been hacked!' A lot of that is the user's fault, but still not all of it is.

Comment: @David Dorward Haha, I had thought of posting FireSheep, but decided against it. Good example.

Comment: @diEcho Even popular websites aren't perfect. (or perhaps, especially popular websites)

Comment: @David but we can't hack any data without that addon... then y so worried??

Comment: @diEcho — the add on isn't a magic bit of unique and secret power. It is a demonstration about how **trivial** it is to break security that only uses HTTPS for the initial authentication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't check the port number for verifying https as it's not impossible -- although highly unlikely -- for https to be on a non-standard port. Rather, check the `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` variable:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/login.php') { // only check https on login
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') {
        // do login stuff
    } else {
        // redirect to https or simply give an error
    }
} elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') {
    // redirect to http
}
```

Comment: @webbiedave i m bit confused, ur condition of `nested if` and `elseif` is same, why so?

Comment: first https check occurs when it's determined that they're trying to login. Second check is performed when they are not. Algorithm is basically: If logging in ensure https, else ensure they're not using https. you can rearrange the logic if you wish (say to do the https check first), but the general concepts are the same.

Comment: if i check this on localhost `var_dump($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443)` returns `bool(true)` whereas ``var_dump($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' )` returns `bool(false)` ????

Comment: if `$_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on'` returns false, then https is not being used. That makes sense. But you shouldn't rely on the port number as the determiner.

Comment: @webbiedave, congrates u got 10k now...:)